# Use winform checkbox to linq query

Tags: c#, winforms, entity-framework, linq, checkbox

Hope I am asking this question in the right way.

I am trying to determine the most efficient way to use checkboxes to alter what is returned from my linq query without having to code for every possible combination.

As an example, I have three checkboxes on my winform that represent three columns that I am trying to query

[ ] Year

[ ] Make

[ ] Model

I am using a linq statement to determine the distinct combinations of year make and model through EF

```
var uniquecombos = cb.MakeModelYear.Where(i => i.Year != null && i.Make != null && i.Model != null).Distinct().ToList();
```

What I would like to do is use the checkboxes on my winform to drive which fields I include in my query.

So

[x] Year

[x] Make

[ ] Model

would yield

```
var uniquecombos = cb.MakeModelYear.Where(i => i.Year != null && i.Make != null).Distinct().ToList();
```

Is there a good way to modify the inputs of the query without having to account for every combination of checkboxes through if statements?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have separate properties you still ned to hceck each one - but you can account for each checkbox combination at the same time:

```
.Where(i => (
             (!cbxYear.Checked  || i.Year != null) && 
             (!cbxMake.Checked  || i.Make != null) && 
             (!cbxModel.Checked || i.Model != null)
            )
```

Comment: Great solution!  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this :

```
var query = cb.MakeModelYear;

if (chkYear.Checked)
    query = query.Where(i => i.Year != null);

if (chkMake.Checked)
    query = query.Where(i => i.Make != null);

if (chkModel.Checked)
    query = query.Where(i => i.Model != null);

var uniquecombos = query.Distinct().ToList();
```